# Возможен ли длинный текст без знаков препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Предыдущим вопросом навеян этот.

Возможно ли в русском языке составить длинное предложение, лишённое запятых, тире, скобок, точек с запятой, двоеточия и прочих знаков препинания (если забыл их упомянуть)? Какую примерно структуру может иметь такое предложение? Можете ли привести пример подобного? Какую длину возможно максимально выжать из такого предложения?

Comment: Точку в конце предложения можно не считать за знак препинания. Суть вопроса в том, чтобы в максимально длинном предложении не требовалось ни единого знака препинания, кроме последней точки. Чуть ниже, в комментариях, я попытался составить образец такого предложения, но сегодня, свежим взглядом, пришёл к выводу, что мой пример всё же требует несколько запятых.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал элементарную формулу для бесконечно длинного предложения, где не нужны знаки препинания, кроме точки.

«Это был старик с бородой и руками с большими плечами и острыми локтями с… и… с… и… с… и…»

Здесь нет однородных членов и сочинительно-подчинительных связей.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, Ваши изыскания не предел, можно ещё добавить однородные члены с союзом И, необособленные определения, частицы и наречия с другим значением.

«В КИПЕЛЬНО-белой сверкающей под светом НОЧНЫХ звёзд накидке с мягким УЗКИМ  меховым подбоем из непроглядного едва шевелящегося мрака засыпающего СЛАДКИМ СНОМ тронного зала сквозь наполненный крикливыми волнистыми попугаями И ЗАСТАВЛЕННЫЙ СОСУДАМИ С ДИКОВИННЫМИ РАСТЕНИЯМИ коридор и СЛОВНО омертвевшую к вечернему часу лоджию СТРАННО тянущейся хромой походкой УСТАЛОГО ЧЕЛОВЕКА  двадцать четвёртого числа предпоследнего зимнего месяца (название месяца) торжественно И ВАЖНО прошествовал пучеглазый сановитый жирный заместитель начальника третьего конного отряда персидской армии пожилой и мудрый визирь Аль Харрез Пуль ибн Хасан С ПУХЛОЙ КРАСНОЙ С ЧЁРНОЙ ОКАНТОВКОЙ КОЖАНОЙ ПАПКОЙ В ПРИЖАТОЙ К ГРУДИ РУКЕ».

Можно и ещё изощриться, только всё равно захочется где-то сделать  пояснительную паузу, потому что такие длинные предложения трудны в прочтении и затруднены в понимании, а потому нежелательны.

Comment: Это замечательно! А что касается знаков препинания? Я нигде не допустил промашки?

Comment: Людмила права, пояснения все же нужны, а следовательно - и запятые. Иначе текст становится нечитаемый.

Comment: В задачу не ставится "читабельность" текста. Исключительно возможность растянуть его на наивозможнейшую длину, не используя знаки препинания. Здесь их не обойти?  p.s. в предложении можно изменить, опустить или прибавить любую часть

Comment: Всё замечательно, только слова "кипельный" в русском языке не существует. Есть слова "кипень", "кипенный". Кипень - белая пена, появляющаяся при кипении.

ХРЮ!

Comment: >Всё замечательно, только слова "кипельный"...     
  
Я перенес как комментарий, поскольку адресовано явно Людмиле.    
Что до меня, то слово настолько распространено, что говорить просто "не существует" уже как-то не получается.  Можно спорить о его нормативности, но вот тут как раз и хотелось бы сначала узнать мнение Людмилы.

> В задачу не ставится "читабельность" текста.  
  
Если не ставить такую задачу, то длина фразы практически неограниченна. "Читабельность" здесь по сути означает наличие смыла. А бессмысленные фразы можно составлять из сколь угодно больших списков слов.

Comment: "Читабельность" здесь по сути означает сложность для восприятия, а не отсутствие смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, по крайней мере, одна точка там точно будет - в конце предложения, иначе это уже не будет полноценным предложением. А в остальном, думаю, что такое возможно. Но хотелось бы послушать мнения специалистов.

Answer (score 0):

1. Как однажды Жак Звонарь городской сломал фонарь.
2. Пойди купи хлеб.
3. Сходи в магазин купи хлеб.
4. Каждая маленькая девочка мечтает о большой любви.
5. Заставить встать пойти купить выпить.

В приведенных примерах отсутствуют запятые, но точка, заканчивающая предложение, должна стоять обязательно. Знак или знаки препинания (запятая/тире) возможны в третьем предложении, но здесь решение принимает автор. Точки обычно не ставятся в газетных заголовках.

Comment: Очевидно, я недостаточно точно сформулировал вопрос. Отсутствие знаков препинания — требование, не относящиеся  к точке, завершающей предложение. Смысл вопроса в том, чтобы растянуть само предложение как можно длиннее, не используя при этом запятых, тире, скобок, кавычек и так далее. Например, при помощи некоторых, вспомненных мной приемов, получилось составить такое вот слегка кривоватое предложение почти в шестьдесят слов:

Comment: «В белой сверкающей под светом звёзд накидке с мягким меховым подбоем из непроглядного едва шевелящегося мрака засыпающего тронного зала сквозь наполненный крикливыми волнистыми попугаями коридор и омертвевшую к вечернему часу лоджию тянущейся хромой походкой двадцать четвёртого числа предпоследнего зимнего месяца торжественно прошествовал пучеглазый сановитый жирный заместитель начальника третьего конного отряда персидской армии пожилой и мудрый визирь Аль Харрез Пуль ибн Хасан».

Comment: Здесь удалось нарастить объём за счёт 1) прилагательных, 2) предлогов «из», «с», «и», «к», 3) причастий, которые, насколько я знаю (в своих знаниях сомневаюсь), не требуют использования запятых, если они расположены перед существительным (если ошибаюсь, поправьте меня).

Comment: Не уверен на счёт отсутствия запятой в месте, что начинается со слова «сквозь». Поправьте, если запятая там необходима. 
Вопрос же в следующем: есть ли ещё какие-либо способы (предлоги, слова-уточнения или стилистические конструкции), которые я не учел, способные увеличить длину такого предложения, не выходя за рамки правил пунктуации русского языка (естественно, не используя при этом знаков препинания)?